# How would I configure my font to be bolder?

Tags: fonts, rxvt

I'm in a bit of dilemma here. I'm using Urxvt as my terminal [Fantasque Sans Mono](https://github.com/belluzj/fantasque-sans) as my font.

Here's the result:

[image]

The regular version is just too skinny for me. So I configured Urxvt to use the bold style:

[image]

Now it's *too bold* for my taste. Is there any way to configure the *font-weight* within ubuntu? Maybe some font-config witchcraft? Or maybe some Infinality magic? I'm completely clueless when it comes to font configuration. I did try infinality's OSX style but it didn't help a lot. Maybe I wasn't doing it right :/

I'm only going through all this trouble because I'd like to start using vim and the font is a big factor here for me.

I love linux and I wouldn't want to be that guy who bought a MacBook just because he liked the terminal's font rendering. That was my goal when I started out with customizing my terminal's font. The closest I got was using Monaco's bold style but it ultimately disables bold styling for me.

I did see a [post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/38585/using-fonts-conf-to-change-the-weight-of-monospace-fonts) involving font boldening and font-config but apparently, you can't control how much the font emboldens.